# Term for calling a non-programmer who has an effective, important role in a project

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, technology, professions

What is the official term (within a (software) project organization) for calling someone who is not a programmer however (s)he plans the nuts and bolts of the system, it goals, challenges and conceptual architecture. (S)He may be called researcher, but I'm looking for a more precise term.

Comment: See also: [workplace.se]

Comment: Why does everyone on a project have to be a programmer? Who says? There are, as the OP already notes, architects, researchers, project managers, systems guys, ...

Comment: May better be asked on a relevant tech site.

Comment: @Kris, I mean a software engineering project.

Comment: Eilia, Yes, even I meant so. Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're describing a *[systems engineer](https://www.asme.org/career-education/articles/certification/certified-systems-engineers-are-in-high-demand)*:

> Systems engineering integrates all engineering disciplines and
>   specialty groups for a project into an efficient, streamlined process
>   that smoothly takes the project from concept to production to
>   operation, meeting all the business and technical goals of the
>   project. [ASME]

Answer (score 1):

How about the "**systems analyst**." (Disclaimer: My wife was a programmer-analyst before she retired.)

The role of the systems analyst is to translate the plain-language, non-technical stated goals of the clent into the pseudo-languages used by programmers deeper in the software development team. A systems analyst can often create a proof-of-concept to demonstrate and debug the function of the intended program.

Answer (score 1):

To **systems engineer** and **systems analyst** I would like to add **architect**, with any appropriate prefixes and qualifications: *systems*, *software*, *hardware*, but also *lead*, *senior*, *principal* (note that "Principal Engineer" can be a legally qualified and restricted term, I believe it is so in Canada).

I would rank the architect above the engineer and the analyst in importance.